str.find() takes no keyword arguments
asdsad = [('https://m.vk.com',),
            ('https://yandex.ru',),
            ('https://cloud.yandex.ru',),
            ('https://www.ya.ru',),
            ('https://www.google.com',),
            ('https://mail.google.com',),
            ('http://www.google.ru',),
            ('https://drive.google.com',),
            ('https://www.google.ru',)]
wasd8 = str(aasdsad[8])

zpa = wasd8.find("g", start=8)

print(aasdsad[8][2:zpa])

мб я чето не понимаю, но я все правильно делаю вроде
ошибка:
D:/py3124/python.exe d:/CodeWWPy/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\CodeWWPy\test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    zpa = wasd8.find("g", start=8)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: str.find() takes no keyword arguments


Давайте переменным нормальные имена

@Kromster, ошибку ещё поправить забыли.

@wchistow отнюдь, специально вам оставил :-)

В ошибке написано: str.find не принимает именованных аргументов - только позиционные. Просто уберите start=:
zpa = wasd8.find("g", start=8)
#                     ------

